# error while returning a char from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, char

```
#define SIZE 1024
char encryptEVEN(char *c)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    char enEVEN[SIZE], temp[SIZE];
    while (/*c[i] != NULL &&*/c[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0 || i - 3 == 0)
        {
            enEVEN[i] = c[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    strcpy(temp, enEVEN);
    return enEVEN;
}

int main()
{
    char charr[SIZE], enEVEN[SIZE];
    strcpy(enEVEN, encryptEVEN(charr));
    printf("%s", enEVEN);
}
```

hello,
I am  trying to pass and return a char in C but I keep getting warnings and no output displayed I think the problem is with the return for the function .. can I get some help

Comment: `enEVEN` is an array; `return enEVEN;` attempts to return a `char *` from a function that is supposed to return `char`.  It is not surprising your compiler is unhappy.  Your code is unreadable.  Please learn to indent systematically.  Note that changing the function to return a `char *` is not a solution; you're then using a variable that is no longer defined, which leads to undefined behaviour (aka mysterious bugs).

Comment: When posting questions about build errors or warning, *show them to us!* Copy the output, as text, in full and complete, then paste it into the question body, without modifications. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show an example of a string and it's encrypted version. Your algorithm in `encryptEVEN` is sufficiently weird that it prevents me from guessing what `encryptEVEN` should do.

Comment: `while (c[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0 || i - 3 == 0)
        {
            enEVEN[i] = c[i];
            i++;
        }
    }` is an infinite loop if `c[0] && c[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but you probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1024

void encryptEVEN(const char *c, char *destination)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  while (c[i] != '\0')
  {
    if (i % 2 == 0 || i - 3 == 0)
    {
      destination[j++] = c[i];
    }

    i++;
  }

  destination[j] = '\0';             // string terminator
}

int main()
{
  char charr[SIZE], enEVEN[SIZE];

  strcpy(charr, "Hello World!");  // put something meaningful into the source string

  encryptEVEN(charr, enEVEN);
  printf("%s\n", enEVEN);
}
```

The output is:

> HlloWrd

Answer (score 4):

You have *two* major problems:

The first is simply that you use the wrong return type. You try to return a pointer (to the first element of `enEVEN`), i.e. something of type `char *`. But the return type is `char`, not a pointer.

The much worse problem though is that you return a pointer to the first element of `enEVEN` which is a *local variable*. Local variables goes out of scope and cease to exist once you return from a function. That means the pointer you want to return will not be valid, it will point to something that doesn't exist once you have executed the `return` statement.

To solve the first problem, change the return type to `char *`. To solve the second problem pass the array `enEVEN` as an *argument* to the function.

---

There's a third problem too, unrelated to the above problems: In the `main` function you don't initialize the `charr` array. Its contents will be *indeterminate* (and seemingly random).

Comment: how to pass enEVEN as an argument ?